# Create an Object inside a loop with a dynamic key name storing another object

Tags: php, object, while-loop

I have an unknown amount of objects which are supposed to be sorted into another object inside a loop with an dynamic game so I can call it later on in my script like this:

```
$object->$variable5->(attribut from my other object)
```

This is what I currently have.

```
$object= new stdClass;
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    $object->variable.$i = $row;
    $i++;
}
```

I tried quiet a bit and searched but I didn't find a real solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$attribute = "$variable$i";
$object->$attribute = $row;
```

But this is only to answer your question about how to do it. As far as I can see, you are better of using an array as a member variable:

```
$object = (object)array($variable => array());
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    $object->{$variable}[] = $row;
    $i++;
}
```

Then you can access `$object->$variable5->(attribut from my other object)` as

```
$object->{$variable}[5]->(attribut from my other object)
```